# dreamweaver regex find and replace to add webp images

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, webp

I want to find all the jpgs in a big static site and add webp

so i need to find

```
<img src="image/path/my be/long/new_2.jpg" alt="descriptive tag blah"  />
```

and replace with

```
         <picture>
            <source srcset="image/path/amy be/long/new_2.webp" type="image/webp"> 
            <img src="image/path/my be/long/new_2.jpg" alt="descriptive tag blah"  />
         </picture>
```

Ive tried all kinds but I'm really unfamiliar with regex, so the closest I've got is

```
<img src="([^"]+)" alt="(.*?)"  />
```

and replace with

```
         <picture>
            <source srcset="$1.webp" type="image/webp"> 
            <img src="$1" alt="$2"  />
         </picture>
```

but that comes up with the file extension   .jpg.webp

regex is such a huge topic any help on this from anyone with some experience will be very welcome

Comment: You can try something like this, which does not include the `.jpg`: `<img src="([a-z0-9\/\s_]+).jpg" alt="(.*?)"  \/>`

Comment: WOW THANK YOU that is PERFECT I cant thank you enough you've made my day

Comment: I post it as an answer so that it is easier to find.

Comment: Ill give it a big tick or best answer - Thanks again

Comment: I clicked the up arow but got..... Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score....

Comment: There should be a button like "accept answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the regex to match the source without `.jpg` you can use this regex:

It matches:

- a-z: lowercase characters
- 0-9: numbers
- \/: slash
- \s: whitespace
- _: underscore

and stops with `.jpg"`

```
<img src="([a-z0-9\/\s_]+).jpg" alt="(.*?)"  \/>
```

Comment: found the "accept answer" and ticked. Thanks again

Comment: For those using dreamweaver and not experienced with regex - like me - This may not find all the occurences of img that you may be looking for. In my case it was extra spaces at the end or in the middle, just go through and check and then add the necessary spaces. In one case I had a carrage return in the middle!